# best practice? where to store an image in angular?

Tags: angular

I'm currently learning angular as I'm about to start a boat load of projects at work using it. Anyways, I'm just playing around with some stuff and I'm having some trouble figuring out the best place to store an image file. I've had success with the index.html file and the style.css setting a background image. But now I'm trying to use some pictures on the component level and just having some difficulty. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you want too many images in your application then upload your images to some server there lots of image servers out there.
But if you have few images then you can store in

```
src/assets/images
```

folder. Access them directly by setting the path in image URL.

Comment: thank you, the assets folder was spot on, works like a charm